# Lights works when car turns on but won't start when I turn the keys. Would it be the starter?

Tags: starter

When I turn my keys and all lights are on but when I try to turn the car on nothing happens. Would it be that my starter is bad and need a new replace? Any help?

Comment: Which vehicle is this? Year/make/model?

Comment: 96 acura integra gsr

Comment: On my particular truck this means replace battery as there's not enough voltage to crank the starter anymore.

Answer (score 3):

### A bad starter is just *one* possibility

Generic culprits for no-cranking include:

- bad starter
- bad starter relay

  If you don't hear a "click" when you try to start the engine this is may be worth checking
- faulty ignition switch

  If the relay doesn't click when the key is turned, but clicks when 12 V is applied to it externally, the switch might be to blame

---

### Recommendation

Consider replacing the starter *after* eliminating the other possibilities.